# ufw won't allow connections to port 5432

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, postgresql, ufw

I've installed Postgresql 9.4 on Ubuntu Trusty from the PGDG ppa. I've created a database and set it `listen-addresses` to '*'. I've made an entry in the pg_hba.conf file. I can connect locally with no trouble. Here is the entry from my pg_hba.conf:

`host    all     tarka   192.168.0.0/24  md5`

The problem is that the port seems blocked by UFW. I've tried several variations of the ufw command to allow postgres such as

`sudo ufw allow postgresql/tcp`

`sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp`

and most recently

`sudo ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 5432`

I've restarted ufw each time.

This is the status currently:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: allow (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
5432                       ALLOW IN    192.168.0.0/24
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

The entries in `iptables` seem valid:

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.0.0/24       anywhere             tcp dpt:postgresql
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.0.0/24       anywhere             udp dpt:postgresql
```

Never the less, when I try to connect from a remote machine, ufw logs:

```
Sep  2 13:55:28 estuary kernel: [242754.395342] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=94:de:80:27:4a:7e:b4:75:0e:97:21:29:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.13 DST=192.168.0.12 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43525 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=36382 DPT=21 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

In fact I can't even connect by disabling ufw. In all cases `nmap` reports the port 5432 is closed:

```
nmap estuary -p5432

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-09-02 16:43 PDT
Nmap scan report for estuary (192.168.0.12)
Host is up (0.0059s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5432/tcp closed postgresql
```

In addition, I'm running `nginx` as a web server and it is completely accessible from the other machine.

How can I get ufw (or whatever is actually doing it) to stop blocking port 5432?

**Edit** as requested:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 estuary:domain          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:51413                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp           *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:smtp                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:6010          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:49152                 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:9091                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:5900                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:http-alt              *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.12:ssh        cutter:46943            ESTABLISHED
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.12:46461      104.28.7.98:http        CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.12:59407      89.234.156.205:http     CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 localhost:38145         localhost:6010          ESTABLISHED
tcp        1      1 192.168.0.12:59404      89.234.156.205:http     LAST_ACK   
tcp        0      0 localhost:6010          localhost:38144         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:6010          localhost:38145         ESTABLISHED
tcp        1      0 192.168.0.12:45068      89.218.2.238.stati:http CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.12:9091       cutter:46825            ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 localhost:38144         localhost:6010          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 [::]:51413              [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:ipp       [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:smtp               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:6010      [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:5900               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

My client (cutter) connects by wireless.

Comment: In your `ufw` log blocked destination port is `DPT=21` not `5432`. Can you give as output from command `netstat -at`

Comment: Did you restart postgresql ? listen_adresses changes require restart... What error message does your distant client give you when you try to connect ?

Comment: Yes I certainly restarted Postgresql. I get the usual message about host not listening on IP/port. The issue seems to be the port is blocked on the server. See the latest edit.

Comment: You're only listening on localhost (127.0.0.1). In your original question you mentioned the "listen_address" parameter.  Should this be "listen_addresses"?

Comment: Yes, it is plural. But it's also set to "*". What makes you say I'm only listening on localhost?

Comment: "tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    \*:\*                     LISTEN" instead of "tcp        0      0 \*:postgresql    \*:\*                     LISTEN"

Comment: Ahh, ok how do I change that?

Comment: Something seems to be amiss with your listen_addresses statement and per the documentation, localhost is the default.  You could try changing it from '*' to '0.0.0.0' or '192.168.0.12'  Or post the statement you have here.  Reference: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-connection.html

Comment: Just noticed in your question you have 'listen-addresses" with a hypen - the documentation has an underscore ('listen_addresses')

Comment: You got it Brandon! Somehow I replace the underscore with a dash. All is well now. Make that an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just noticed in your question you have 'listen-addresses' with a hyphen - the documentation has an underscore ('listen_addresses')

Comment: Man my eyes are getting bad.

Comment: Do like I do and blame it on the font ;-)